# addAttachment does not add any attachment to email

Tags: laravel, phpmailer, attachment

I have the following code written out and the email sends fine and all but I have not been able to figure out why the email does not include the intended attachment (the pdf file).

I have also tried $mail->attach with MIME and that gives a 500 internal server error.

```
    $pdf = public_path() . '/assets/attachments/TermSheet.pdf';
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = '';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    //ENV VARIABLES
    $mail->Host =  env("MAIL_HOST");
    $mail->Port = env("MAIL_PORT");
    $mail->Username = env("MAIL_USERNAME");
    $mail->Password = env("MAIL_PASSWORD");
    $mail->SetFrom($fromemail, $fromname);
    $mail->Subject = $emailsubject;

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $emailsubject;
    $mail->addAttachment($pdf);
    $mail->Body    = $initbody;  
    $mail->AddAddress($user);
    if(isset($ccemaillist)){                        //cc
        $ccemail = explode(";",$ccemaillist);
        foreach ($ccemail as $toccmail) {
            $mail->AddAddress($toccmail);
        }
    }                  

    if($mail->Send()) {    

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $currentapp.'/mail/send?api_user_id='.$creatorid);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                    "recipient_email=$user&email_type=WelcomeEmail&sys_status=1&creator=$creatorid");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close ($ch);     

        return "SUC";
    }
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, any input in this I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Double check your path.  `addAttachment` will return `false` if it cannot access the file.

Comment: The path is correct, at the moment I'm able to get the attachment with  $mail->addStringAttachment($attachment, $filename); but the file comes out corrupted

Comment: Ok, so you’re saying that `var_dump($mail->addAttachment($pdf));` shows `true`? Also, why not use `addCC` for your CC addresses?

Comment: Yes that is the plan for the cc, this is a code I based off some tutorials. For now my focus was to fix the email and I finally managed to do it ^^ The solution : $mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents($attachment), $filename); where $attachments is the full path to the file.

Comment: That is what `addAttachment` does. Use the right function.

Comment: I've been trying to use AddAttachment since the moment I was working on this project, bro, yet no matter what I tried AddAttachment doesn't include any attachments in the email. However, with the same path to the file, (both in my storage or public) for my laravel project, addStringAttachment works. Why is that? How do I make addattachment work instead?

Comment: What happened when you did what I said earlier?

Comment: var_dump() doesn't print anything. The api just goes ahead with the function and executes it.

Comment: What happened when you did what I said earlier?

Comment: Then there is something very wrong with your PHP installation.

Answer (score 0):

It may give

> 500 internal server error

Due to incorrect file paths.

You may try like
`$pdf = asset('assets/attachments/TermSheet.pdf');`
public_path() does not work in some cases.

Comment: I don't think PHPMailer is looking for a URL

Comment: I don't get any 500 internal server error unless im using $mail->attach(); however by using addAttachment() I'm able to send the mail but the attachment is not included in the received email. Hard coding the pdf url returns nothing as well

Comment: Did you try this? $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";

Comment: Yes I did, that didn't work either. Instead of addAttachment, I used addStringAttachment and now it works.